# switch statement inside while loop and validating values read in from file

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, exception, switch-statement

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Marks
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String fileName;
        int studentCount;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter file name");
        fileName = sc.nextLine();
        studentCount = numLine(fileName);
        String arrayString[] = new String[studentCount];
        double arrayReal[] = new double[studentCount];
        readFile(fileName, arrayString, arrayReal);
    }



    public static int numLine (String fileName)
    {
        FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
        InputStreamReader rdr;
        BufferedReader bufRdr;
        int lineNum=0;
        String line;
        try
        {
            fileStrm = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
            bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);


            line = bufRdr.readLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                lineNum++;
               line = bufRdr.readLine();
            }
            fileStrm.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            if(fileStrm != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileStrm.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex2){}
            }
            System.out.println("error in file processing"+ e.getMessage());
        }
        return lineNum;
    }

    public static void readFile(String fileName, String arrayString[], double arrayReal[])
    {
        FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
        InputStreamReader rdr;
        BufferedReader bufRdr;
        int lineNum;
        String line;
        try
        {
            fileStrm = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
            bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
            for(int i=0;i<arrayString.length;i++)
            {
                line = bufRdr.readLine();
                arrayString[i] = processString(line);
                arrayReal[i] = processReal(line);
            }
            choice(arrayString, arrayReal);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            if(fileStrm != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileStrm.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex2){}
            }
            System.out.println("error in file processing");
        }
    }



    public static String processString(String line)
    {
        String stringPart;
        String lineArray[] = line.split(",");
        stringPart = lineArray[0];
        return stringPart;
    }



    public static double processReal(String line)
    {
        double realPart;
        String lineArray[] = line.split(",");
        realPart = Double.parseDouble (lineArray[1]);
        if (realPart<0 || realPart>100)
        {
            System.out.println("invalid testmark");
        }
        return realPart;
    }

    public static void choice( String arrayString[], double arrayReal[])
    {
        int choice;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1.display mark");
        System.out.println("2.exit");
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        if (choice == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("exiting");
        }
        while (choice !=2)
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    output(arrayString, arrayReal);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("exiting");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("invalid choice choose between 1 and 2");
            }
            System.out.println("1.display marks");
            System.out.println("2.exit");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }



    public static void output(String arrayString[], double arrayReal[])
    {
        String name;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0;i<arrayString.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arrayString[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("enter stident name");
        for (int j=0;j<arrayString.length;j++)
        {
            if (arrayString[j].equals(name))
            {
                System.out.println("mark of " + arrayString[j] + "is " + arrayReal[j]);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is a code which takes in name and marks from a csv file. it compiles and works partly. i want to check the file for valid values eg. marks between 0 and 100 and if its not valid quit out of program, but my program just displays "invalid mark" and continues. also if the file is empty print out saying the file is empty. i have no clue as to where to put the code and how. lastly i want it to keep looping until a valid name is input, however when i test it after second loop i get exception in thread "main" error. i know for sure my choice method and catching exception is not correct,but i cant think of any other way to change it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Two things that might help:

1. If you want to exit, use `System.exit(0);`
2. Don't keep creating new `Scanner`s with `new Scanner(System.in)` everywhere.

Create just one and use it throughout the program, like this:

```
 public class Marks {
    // Set up global Scanner "sc" that we'll use everywhere
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]){
       ...
       // Don't make a new scanner, just use the global one
       // Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
    ....
    public static void choice(){
        // Don't create scanner again; just use the global one
        // Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ...
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        ...
    }
```